# Navigate to specific location in react app by link address?

Tags: reactjs

I have a react app site with some components.
I want to navigate directly to specific location in my app by url address.

this is the site url: https://baryogo.co.il

this is my routes:

> ```
>           <Route path='/home' component={Menu} />
>           <Route path='/contactus' component={Contactus} />
>           {/* <Route path='/ourservices' component={OurServices} /> */}
>           <Route path='/gallery' component={Gallerya} />
>           <Route path='/ourcustomers' component={OurCustomers} />
>           <Route exact path="/view-category-details/:id" component={ViewCategoryDetails} />
>           <Route exact path="/view-category-images/:title" component={ViewCategoryImages} />
> ```

when I'm trying to get to [www.baryogo.co.il/gallery](http://www.baryogo.co.il/gallery) for exemple it's work,

but when I'm trying to get directly to view-category-details or view-category-images with specific id or title it's shows blank.

like this url:
https://baryogo.co.il/view-category-details/0

Answer (score 1):

That's because React is client-rendered. The Routing you see from React-Router is only visual.

When you're navigating to the URL `https://myurl.com/path/to/page` you're instructing the browser to initiate a request to that location. If your app is not server-side rendered, then your server doesn't see anything in that location. When you build your client-rendered React app, there's a single index.html, which is what the server sees when you go to the path where it is placed. For example at `https://myurl.com/myreactapp` but that's the only file available as a client-rendered app. If you try to access `https://myurl.com/myreactapp/myroute` the server sees nothing there because there's nothing there.

To incorporate such functionality with a React app, you need to make it server-side rendered, or to make it statically generated so that the routes/pages are generated separately on build time.
There are ways to do this manually but for most people I'd recommend using [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) or [Gatsby.js](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/). Next.js being my personal recommendation as it offers both Server-Side Rendering (SSR) and Static Site Generation (SSG) while Gatsby is only a Static Site Generator.

I hope that answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

### Actually, your provided code example is not enough to tell your issues

**Here is a very simple implementation to follow:**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Link, BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";

const users = [
  {
    name: `Dwayne`
  },
  {
    name: `The Rock`
  },
  {
    name: `Johnson`
  }
];

const UsersPage = () => {
  return (
    <>
      {users.map((user, index) => (
        <h5 key={index}>
          <Link to={`/user/${index + 1}`}>{user.name}'s Page</Link>
        </h5>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

const UserPage = ({ match, location }) => {
  const {
    params: { userId }
  } = match;

  return (
    <>
      <p>
        <strong>User ID: </strong>
        {userId}
      </p>
      <p>
        <strong>User Name: </strong>
        {users[userId - 1].name}
      </p>
    </>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <section className="App">
      <Router>
        <Link to="/users">Users</Link>
        <Route exact path="/users" component={UsersPage} />
        <Route exact path="/user/:userId" component={UserPage} />
      </Router>
    </section>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```